# Twilio: Design for disposing the purchased phone number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I looked at Twilio's [Masked Phone Numbers tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/masked-numbers-java-servlets). It mentions that we can create "disposable" phone numbers.
My question is: **How/ when to dispose those purchased numbers on-demand?**

You can imagine our app to be like Uber, where riders and drivers need to communicate anonymously just for the duration of the ride.

When the ride starts, we purchase a number using the Twilio API. But, when the ride finishes, should I

(1) **release** the phone number and purchase a new phone number for every new ride? This will be easy to implement.

OR

(2) keep the purchased number and **reuse** it to avoid the charge for buying a new phone number for every ride (the $1/month charge for a new phone number)? But, the overhead is to keep track of the purchased phone numbers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend that you keep a pool of numbers that you can use to avoid incurring a charge every time you need a new number, but build your system to be able to purchase a new number if the pool is exhausted. Once you start buying numbers, when the ride is finished you can inspect how many numbers you have and compare to your pool size, releasing the number if you are over your default pool size. Alternatively, you could mark numbers as permanent and temporary and always release temporary numbers.

This is a bit of a wide question, there's many answers, so it's not ideal for Stack Overflow. If you want to chat more about this, let me know in the comments and I will share my email address.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I would like to talk more about it. Please share your email address and I can contact you there. We can delete the comment with your email afterwards.

Comment: Cool, you can get me on philnash@twilio.com.